# Sqlite3 Spliting a String Column returned from a Select Query into multiple columns with a delimiter

Tags: sqlite

I have a query on a READ ONLY database that currently returns me a result like this. This is not a table.

```
ID|METRIC


1|"123,456,789"
2|"546,123,789"
```

Is there a way I can recursively select from that query such that result looks like this - essentially splitting the string among the comma delimiters into their own columns. Ideally something like Select ---some stuff here --- from (--original query--);

```
 1|"123|456|789"
 2|"546|123|789"
```

The other answers I have seen create views or tables which I won't have permission to do. The database is locked to just non-volatile select statements.

Comment: Is the number of comma separated items always 3 or not?

Comment: @forpas The number of items is always 3. The length between the commas can vary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that readable but it works:

```
select id,
  substr(metric, 1, instr(metric, ',') - 1) col1,
  substr(substr(metric, length(substr(metric, 1, instr(metric, ',') - 1)) + 2), 1, instr(substr(metric, length(substr(metric, 1, instr(metric, ',') - 1)) + 2), ',') - 1) col2,
  substr(substr(metric, length(substr(metric, 1, instr(metric, ',') - 1)) + 2), instr(substr(metric, length(substr(metric, 1, instr(metric, ',') - 1)) + 2), ',') + 1) col2
from tablename
```

With a CTE:

```
with qry as (
  select 
    id, 
    substr(metric, 1, instr(metric, ',') - 1) col1, 
    substr(metric, instr(metric, ',') + 1) right1 from tablename
)

select 
  id, 
  col1, 
  substr(right1, 1, instr(right1, ',') - 1) col2, 
  substr(right1, instr(right1, ',') + 1) col3
from qry q
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=6c5d731736ea99e55151e63f1079749f)